# R: is.na() does not pick up NA value

Tags: r

So I have a dataset and just by looking at it there are clear NA's in the dataset.

```
 > dput(bmi.cig)
structure(list(MSI.subset.BMI = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", 
"NA"), class = "factor"), MSI.subset.Cigarette = structure(c(3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "NA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MSI.subset.BMI", 
"MSI.subset.Cigarette"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")


> head(bmi.cig)
  MSI.subset.BMI MSI.subset.Cigarette
1             NA                   NA
2             NA                   NA
3             NA                   NA
4             NA                   NA
5             NA                   NA
6             NA                   NA
```

I want to remove any row that contains an NA in either column, so I'm using the list-wise deletion function `ld` in the `ForImp` package. However, R is not recognizing the NA values.

```
is.na(bmi.cig$MSI.subset.BMI)
```

I get

```
    > is.na(bmi.cig$MSI.subset.BMI)
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[26] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

So once I use the `ld` function I just get an empty dataset in return.

Comment: The values in the columns are not `NA` but `"NA"` strings. See `levels( bmi.cig$MSI.subset.BMI)`.

Comment: Ok. How can I change them from "NA" strings to NA? My goal is just to use the ld function and perform a list-wise deletion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's b/c the columns are factors, and the levels are `"NA"`. I.e., try

```
data <- structure(list(MSI.subset.BMI = structure(c(4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
+ 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 
+ 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", 
+ "NA"), class = "factor"), MSI.subset.Cigarette = structure(c(3L, 
+ 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
+ 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1", 
+ "2", "NA"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("MSI.subset.BMI", 
+ "MSI.subset.Cigarette"), row.names = c(NA, 30L), class = "data.frame")
> class(blah[,1])

data[,1]=="NA"
```

The `NA`'s are actually characters (`class("NA")`), not class `logical` like `class(NA)`.

Comment: I see. How can I change them to from "NA" to NAs for the entire dataset?

Comment: if you want to filter out the NAs you can do something like this:
`msi[msi$MSI.subset.BMI != "NA"  & msi$MSI.subset.BMI != "NA",]`, that should work on your data frame and leave you with what you wanted

Comment: Depends on what stage of your code you want to make the change – if you read in the data from a .csv, for example, you could try the stringsAsFactors=FALSE argument. If you want to correct the `data` object, you could do `data[data=="NA"] <- NA`

Answer (score 2):

As @rbatt mentions, you have character NA values as factor levels.  You can remove them and get the NA entries to register as real `NA` values for the entire data set with

```
df[] <- lapply(df, function(x) {
    is.na(levels(x)) <- levels(x) == "NA"
    x
})
```

where `df` is your data set.  And now test with

```
is.na(df)
```