# NA values are not recognized properly using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, na

I have a dataset with two columns, in one of them are missing values.
I load it using

```
data <- read_excel("file.xlsx") %>%
  select("ID", "Value")
```

The tibble looks like that

| ID | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| NA | 4 |
| 32 | 1 |

The NAs are recognized as such.
However, I use

```
data["ID"=="NA"] <- NA
```

to ensure that this is not the problem ([R: is.na() does not pick up NA value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30381152/r-is-na-does-not-pick-up-na-value/30381226)).

When I try to filter:

```
data %>%
filter(!is.na(ID))
```

the whole tibble stays the same, and no row is deleted.
So I try

```
data %>%
mutate(
isna <- is.na(ID)
)
```

and all isna are FALSE.

Why doesn't recognize dplyr the NAs?

I am grateful for every help!

Comment: Did you check if that `NA` is actual `NA` and not a string ?

Comment: yes! That's why I used: `data["ID"=="NA"] <- NA`

Comment: @C.Sebastian That code doesn’t do what you want it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO! Use this to get NAs mutated and then delete the NAs:

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(ID = ifelse(ID == "NA",NA,ID)) %>%
  filter(!is.na(ID))
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked! One problem could have also been that the column name, which I proxied here with ID, consisted originally of two words, i.e. "identifier number". So instead of ID in your code, I tried 'identifier number', and it seems that dplyr doesn't like this way of column name.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to validate one of the answer @C.Sebastian

Comment: @C.Sebastian sorry, didn't pay attention to the last part of your answer. Use ` `identifer number` ` to make it work

Answer (score 2):

```
data["ID"=="NA"] <- NA
```

does nothing. The condition `"ID"=="NA"` is always `FALSE`, since you are comparing two unequal string literals (`"ID"` and `"NA"`). To fix it, use e.g.

```
data[data$ID == "NA", "ID"] <- NA
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I get the error (the dataset has 167 rows in total): `Error: Must assign to columns with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 2 but subscript `data$ID == "NA"` has size 167.`

Comment: @C.Sebastian Yes, my code was completely wrong, sorry about that. And two people upvoted it despite that! Corrected it now.

Answer (score 0):

Why not directly

```
data %>%
  filter(ID != "NA")
```

or

```
subset(data, ID != "NA")
```